# ошибка вывода времени DS3231, arduino, esp32

Tags: arduino

пытаюсь запихнуть время в переменную, чтобы дальше можно было пользоваться этой строкой, но вместо времени получаю какую-то чертовщину, то ли мусор из памяти, то ли выводит обkать памяти с другой переменной, кто-то сталкивался с этим?

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
   if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  delay(500);
}
String time_now ;
long prntTime = 0;
void loop() {

  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  if (millis() > prntTime )
  {
    prntTime = millis() + 1000;
    String time_now = now.year() + '/' + now.month() + '/' + now.day() + " " + now.hour() + ':' + now.minute() + ':' + now.second();
    delay (20);
    Serial.println(time_now);
    delay (20);
  }

}
```

вывод в терминал:

```
17:08:04.592 -> 
17:08:05.584 -> port.
17:08:05.584 -> 
17:08:06.611 -> ort.
17:08:06.611 -> 
17:08:07.600 -> rt.
17:08:07.600 -> 
17:08:08.594 -> t.
17:08:08.594 -> 
17:08:09.617 -> .
17:08:14.601 -> E (%d) %s: Please enable CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE option in menuconfig.
17:08:14.601 -> 
17:08:15.625 ->  (%d) %s: Please enable CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE option in menuconfig.
17:08:15.625 -> 
17:08:16.609 -> (%d) %s: Please enable CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE option in
```

причем если вывожу напрямую в консоль - все работает.

```c
        Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
        Serial.print('/');
        Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
        Serial.print('/');
        Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
        Serial.print(':');
        Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
        Serial.print(':');
        Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
        Serial.println();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что по-вашему делает это выражение?

```
now.year() + '/' + now.month() + '/' + now.day() + " " + now.hour() + ':' + now.minute() + ':' + now.second();
```

Методы `year()`, `month()` и т.п. возвращают целочисленные значения. Символьные константы `'/'`, `':'` - это тоже целочисленнные значения.

При помощи оператора `+` вы суммируете все эти целочисленные значения (что уже само по себе бессмысленно) и прибавляете результат к строковому литералу `" "`, который какими-то судьбами затесался в ваше выражение. Строковый литерал здесь выступает в роли указателя `const char *`, к которому вы прибавляете полученное странное целочисленное значение. В результате такой адресной арифметики получается указатель `const char *`, указывающий "непонятно куда", который вы используете для инициализации своего `String time_now`. Программа будет либо падать, либо выводить мусор.

Спасти ситуацию можно сразу приведя первое слагаемое к типу `String`

```
String(now.year()) + '/' + now.month() + '/' + now.day() + " " + now.hour() + ':' + now.minute() + ':' + now.second();
```

В таком случае оператор `+` будет означать символьную конкатенацию, а не арифметическое суммирование.

Comment: спасибо! подумал раз переменная объявлена как String, то вместо суммирования будет конкатенация.

Comment: @Igor T.: В С++ левая часть присваивания или инициализации никак не влияет на интерпретацию выражения в правой части. Т.е. вышепроцитированное выражение рассматривается независимо от того, что там у вас за переменная инициализируется.